# Understanding for in loop (javascript)

Tags: javascript, iterator, for-in-loop

Im kinda new to JS and I'm trying to understand how for/in loop really works, here's some sample code:

```
phoneBook = {};
phoneBook.bill = { name : "bill", lastName "hayder" };
phoneBook.steve = { name : "steve", lastName "garcia" };

for ( obj in phoneBook )
{
    console.log(obj);
};
```

When I run this code I get bill and steve as an output, my question is if that's what the iterator holds why I am allowed to do phoneBook[obj] and work with that?? If I type manually phoneBook[bill] I get an error, I can only phoneBook.bill or phoneBook["bill"].

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Because `bill` as an identifier is undefined. JS syntax only allows for `objectName["property"]` or `objectName.property`. If `bill` was a variable of a string, it would work. That’s exactly the case with `obj` — it’s a string.

Comment: For more informaion you can check how working with objects work in js https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Ref: [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `phonebook[something]` it means that `something` should be an expression that returns a string, and it should find the property whose name is that string.

In the case of `phonebook[obj]`, the value of the variable `obj` will be the string `"bill"` or `"steve"`, and it will then look up the corresponding property.

If you write `phonebook[bill]`, it tries to use `bill` as a variable name, and expects it to contain a string that names a property. But there is no variable named `bill`, so this gets an error.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript objects are simply key-value pairs.

```
phoneBook = {};
phoneBook.bill = { name : "bill", lastName: "hayder" };
phoneBook.steve = { name : "steve", lastName: "garcia" };
```

In this example, the `phoneBook` object has two key-value properties, `bill` and `steve`. But the properties themselves are objects, each containing the properties `name` and `lastName`.

Key-value pairs can be accessed via two ways: the object way and the dictionary way. Object way means accessing via `phoneBook.bill`, and dictionary way means accessing via `phoneBook['bill']`. Notice that using a dictionary way means simply passing the property name to the object.

Now, `phoneBook[bill]` is invalid because JS thinks that bill is a variable, and tries to find this. That's why you should use `phoneBook['bill']` or `phoneBook["bill"]`. You can use this dictionary form, but I suggest you use the `phoneBook.bill` method.

I hope I answered your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

some syntax errors fixed

```
phoneBook = {};
phoneBook.bill = { name: "bill", lastName: "hayder" };
phoneBook.steve = { name: "steve", lastName: "garcia" };

for (obj in phoneBook)
{
    console.log(obj);
};
```

**Javascript basics**

phoneBook has a property bill

In javascript this  property bill can be referenced using

- `phoneBook.bill`
- `phoneBook['bill']`

when you reference phoneBook[bill] you will recieve an error because javascript is looking for a variable that contains the **string** **bill**

what you can do is try it this way

```
var bill = 'bill';
phoneBook[bill]
```